# Parsing SOAP response with SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I am trying to call a soap server method. Everything works fine except one thing. I get a respone from the server in XML format. So far so good. But the problem is that i need to get the values of the XML and normally i do that just with a foreach and get the values i need. But this time the name of the child i need to get data from is called: 'return'. So i can not reference to that in a foreach function.

Could someone tell me how i can reach the same result but with a different way?

My answer from the server:

```
<soap:envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:body>
<ns2:getauthresponse xmlns:ns2="http://dpd.com/common/service/types/LoginService/2.0" xmlns:ns3="http://dpd.com/common/service/exceptions">
<return>
    <delisid>thedelisid</delisid>
    <customeruid>thecustomerid</customeruid>
    <authtoken>theauthenticationcode</authtoken>
    <depot>thedepot</depot>
</return>
</ns2:getauthresponse>
</soap:body>
</soap:envelope>
```

the code i would normally use to get the result:

```
foreach($xml->return->authtoken as $authtoken)
{
print_r($authtoken);
}
```

The problem is the return sign here, php keeps seeing it as the return statement.

I also made it an array using new SimpleXMLElement.

And the error i get when i run the code is:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

How can i get the value of authtoken?

All the code:

```
$xml_getAuth = '
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
     xmlns:ns="http://dpd.com/common/service/types/LoginService/2.0">
     <soapenv:Header/>
     <soapenv:Body>
     <ns:getAuth>
     <delisId>'.$delisId.'</delisId>
     <password>'.$password.'</password>
     <messageLanguage>'.$messageLanguage.'</messageLanguage>
     </ns:getAuth>
     </soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Envelope>
    ';

    $headers_getAuth = array(
        "POST  HTTP/1.1",
        "Content-type: application/soap+xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
        "SOAPAction: \"http://dpd.com/common/service/LoginService/2.0/getAuth\"",
        "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_getAuth)
    );

    $getAuth = curl_init('https://public-ws-stage.dpd.com/services/LoginService/V2_0/');
    curl_setopt($getAuth, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($getAuth, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($getAuth, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($getAuth, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers_getAuth);
    curl_setopt($getAuth, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml_getAuth");
    curl_setopt($getAuth, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $output_getAuth = curl_exec($getAuth);

    //Gebruikernsaam en wachtwoord komen niet overeen
    if(strpos($output_getAuth,'LOGIN_8') !== false)
    {
        echo "Verkeerde gebruikernsaam of wachtwoord, neem contact op met uw systeembeheerder voor meer informatie.";
        exit;
    }

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($output_getAuth);

foreach($xml->return->authtoken as $authtoken)
{
print_r($authtoken);
}
```

Answer from the soap call:

```
stdClass Object ( [return] => stdClass Object ( [delisId] => delisid [customerUid] => custid [authToken] => authtoken [depot] => depot ) )
```

Comment: Where is the problem, just do that.

Comment: @colburton How do you mean just do that, php gives the error that the values in the foreach are not valid. That is because there is a return in the compare area. That is not valid. But how can i make it valid?

Comment: What error do you get? Looping over authtoken seems odd since there is only one value.

Comment: @Jack No, when i run the scripts. I get the error:Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Could you show us how you're parsing that data? Btw, you should really use SoapClient here.

Comment: Invalid argument is because authtoken is not an array. It is a string.

Comment: @Samuel how do you mean $xml['return']?

Comment: @colburton no because i made it an array using: new SimpleXMLElement

Comment: @user3734231 You could have saved time if you'd added the error you were getting in the original question. It's a lot harder to help otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should probably be using [`SoapClient`](http://php.net/soapclient) instead of SimpleXML. For example:

```
$c = new SoapClient('https://public-ws-stage.dpd.com/services/LoginService/V2_0/?WSDL');

$res = $c->getAuth(array(
    'delisId' => 'foo',
    'password' => 'bar',
    'messageLanguage' => 'en-us',
));

echo $res->result->authToken;
```

That said, using xpath solves many problems:

```
<?php

$response = <<<XML
<soap:envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:body>
<ns2:getauthresponse xmlns:ns2="http://dpd.com/common/service/types/LoginService/2.0" xmlns:ns3="http://dpd.com/common/service/exceptions">
<return>
    <delisid>thedelisid</delisid>
    <customeruid>thecustomerid</customeruid>
    <authtoken>theauthenticationcode</authtoken>
    <depot>thedepot</depot>
</return>
</ns2:getauthresponse>
</soap:body>
</soap:envelope>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);

foreach ($xml->xpath('//return') as $tmp) {
    echo "authtoken = ", $tmp->authtoken, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this also returns nothing.

Comment: i added all the code i use now, but that does not really matter because i am getting the good response from the server.

Comment: @user3734231 Use `simplexml_load_string()` and not `new SimpleXMLElement()`. Also, why are you not using SoapClient?

Comment: it is not possible with this webservice. So i had to use cURL

Comment: @user3734231 It's certainly possible to use SoapClient; added an example.

Comment: oke it works indeed, that is very nice. But how can i extract the authtoken now?

Comment: @user3734231 The result is stored in `$res`.

Comment: yes i understand, but when i try to reach it with the foreach loop created above then it still gives the same error. Wrong argument for foreach()

Comment: @user3734231 Why are you still trying to perform a `foreach` on that? Did you even try to, say, do `print_r($res)` to see what's inside?

Comment: yes i did and then i get a object returned, i'll post the answer above in my question. And i also can not reach it as an array.

Comment: i posted the answer above in my question

Comment: Nvm, i fixed it by your previous answer. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Jack, could you maybe give me some help with another question?